# How can I view the history of what variable I've looked up before with describe-variable?

Tags: variables, help, history-variables

Whenever I call

```
(describe-variable)
```

, there is no history of what variables I've recently viewed. Is there a way to enable it to have some kind of history?;)

Comment: You can do `l` in a `*Help*` buffer to go back in history, but you cannot select just variables: you'll get all of them (functions, keys, variables, anything). See `help-go-back` and `help-xref-stack`.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "No", you can't do this out of the box, AFAIK.

---

`C-h v` (bound to `describe-variable`) uses `completing-read` with a `nil` value as its `HISTORY` argument.  That means it uses `minibuffer-history` as the history variable, and the value of that variable mixes in lots of minibuffer inputs that you've entered, for different kinds of commands (it's a catch-all).

You would need to advise `describe-variable` to change its `interactive` spec to use `completing-read` with a specific (new) variable as the `HISTORY` argument, e.g. `my-C-v-history`.  Then you could just use `C-h v my-C-h-v-history`, to see its value at any time.

Alternatively, you could define your own command `my-describe-variable`, which does that (just copy the `describe-variable` code and change that `nil` to `my-C-h-v-history`), and bind your command to `C-h v`.

---

FWIW, `C-h M-n M-n`... cycles through **all** of the variables, not just those you've entered as input to `C-h v`, but it may be worth knowing this fact.  They're not in a recognizable order, however (the order is their order as symbols in `obarray`).